# How to Get Members by Place Id using REST API v3.14?

Tags: api, rest, jive

Using `Jive`  `REST API v3.14`, tried allot but no use, no where I found the solution to get members based on place id other than Group.

Actually my task is to get the members of a particular place. Followers are different form members & I could able to get only Group members but what about the space and project members?

Can anyone help me out of this please?

Comment: Only Social Groups have "members".  Projects and Spaces don't.  Perhaps you are looking for a list of users that have access to a Project or Space?  Or users that have posted/participated in a Project or Space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, after a long research & with the help of Jive Community, i got it.

Spaces and projects do not have member lists as social groups do. Access to spaces is managed by permission groups and user permission overrides via the admin console. To determine what users have access to a specific space, you could check the appliedEntitlements service on the place which would look like this: /api/core/v3/places/placeId/appliedEntitlements

This will return either the set of users and security groups and their permissions for this space, or an empty list which indicates that the permissions are inherited from the parent space.

Projects inherit permissions from it's parent space/group.

Please visit [JiveCommunity](https://community.jivesoftware.com/thread/296102) for detail...